iPhone first start wizard did not ask for appleID
iPhone 11, iOS 18.x
Despite having a 4G connection with sim card while doing the first time wizard, I could only login to my appleID/iCloud after the first time wizard finished. Apart from this little weirdness, the phone works 100% including all features.
As far as I remember, the apple ID is asked during the process.
Is this something expected to happen? The iphone activation phase was a bit of longer than usual.

Just guessing here but perhaps the network was not up to Apple's standards for a smooth setup experience. As long as you were able to log in to your Apple ID, I would venture to say that as long as everything works there is nothing to worry about... IMHO
